# NullException в лямбда-выражении

Tags: c#, lambda, null

Возможно, я не правильно понимаю работу лямбда-выражений, но вот этот exception мне иногда вылетает. Причём именно иногда

[image: Иногда возникающее исключение]

[image: Дополнение к исключению]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И подробнее о том, что должно было произойти: я должен был скачать из маркетплейса все продажи одного человека (реального). Каждая продажа содержит от 1 до 10 предметов. На каждый предмет в каждой продаже может быть от 0 до 2 отзывов (1 - оставленный продавцом и 1 - покупателем).

Тот код, что обращается к маркетплейсу, отработал верно - без малого 100 продаж мне для тестирования. Тот код, что получает отзывы тоже - порядка 130 отзывов есть (есть и такие, где только 1 участник отзыв оставил, и такие, где оба промолчали, и такие, где оба высказались). И далее мне необходимо отзывы сохранить у себя в БД, причём сразу привязанными к проданному предмету.

И вот тут происходит то, что показано на скриншотах. Причём из 5 раз, когда этот код был запущен, 4 раза в одном и том же месте вылетел данный exception. А 1 раз код полностью отработал верно. Прошу любой помощи, ибо я не понимаю даже, как так возможно, что один и тот же код с одними и теми же входными данными возвращает разные результаты

**UPD1:** Код запускается в 1 поток, распараллеливание я тут не делал

**UPD2:** `feedbacks` - коллекция отзывов, полученная с маркетплейса. Сама коллекция быть нулом не может (хотя и может содержать 0 элементов), однако может не найтись подходящего по условиям отзыва, и в таком случае `feedbackSeller` окажется нулом.

Трассировка стека:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at XXXXXXXX.Controllers.TestController.<>c__DisplayClass10_5.<TEST>b__14(GetFeedbackResponseFeedbackDetailArrayFeedbackDetail u) in D:\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\XXXXXXXX\Controllers\TestController.cs:line 449
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at XXXXXXXX.Controllers.TestController.TEST() in D:\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\XXXXXXXX\Controllers\TestController.cs:line 449
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at XXXXXXXX.Controllers.TestController.<>c__DisplayClass10_5.<TEST>b__14(GetFeedbackResponseFeedbackDetailArrayFeedbackDetail u) in D:\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\XXXXXXXX\Controllers\TestController.cs:line 449
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at XXXXXXXX.Controllers.TestController.TEST() in D:\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\XXXXXXXX\Controllers\TestController.cs:line 449
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Ну а что такое feedbacks? Это что то отложенное? Оно может содержать null?

Comment: Что у вас в трассировке стека лежит?

Comment: @tym32167 , спасибо, дополнил вопрос

Comment: Сама быть нуллом не может, но может ли содержать в себе нулл- элемент?

Comment: @tym32167 , нет

Comment: что находится в том месте, куда указывает трассировка стека?

Comment: @tym32167 , ``var feedbackSeller = feedbacks.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ItemID == marketplaceSale.Items[i].MarketplaceItemId && u.TransactionID == marketplaceSale.Items[i].TransactionID && u.Role == "Seller");`` - та строка, что на скринах показана

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написано же явно

> **u** was `null`

У вас в коллекции `feedbacks` есть элементы со значением `null`. Это просто факт.

Попробуйте вот так

```csharp
var feedbackSeller = feedbacks.FirstOrDefault(u => u?.ItemID == marketplaceSale.Items[i].MarketplaceItemId && u?.TransactionID == marketplaceSale.Items[i].TransactionID && u?.Role == "Seller");
```

или так

```csharp
var feedbackSeller = feedbacks.FirstOrDefault(u => u != null && u.ItemID == marketplaceSale.Items[i].MarketplaceItemId && u.TransactionID == marketplaceSale.Items[i].TransactionID && u.Role == "Seller");
```

Comment: Три дня тестирования - ни одного повторения ошибки. Спасибо